# Change background images with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a ".jumbotron" in which I need to change background-images just with timer. I tried to manage that with JQuery, but the script doesn't work. Here is it:

```
var imgHead = [
    'cover.jpg',
    'cover1.jpg',
    'cover2.jpg'
];
function Jumbotron(){
    if(i > (imgHead.length - 1)){
        $('.jumbotron').animate({'opacity': '0'}, 200, function(){
            i = 1;
            $('.jumbotron').css('background-image', 'url("+imgHead[0]+")');
        });
        $('.jumbotron').animate({'opacity': '1'}, 200);
    } else {
        $('.jumbotron').animate({'opacity': '0'}, 200, function(){
            $('.jumbotron').css('background-image', 'url("+imgHead[i]+")');
            i++;
        });
        $('.jumbotron').animate({'opacity': '1'}, 200);
    };
};
var intervalJumbotron = setInterval(Jumbotron, 3000);
```

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/jDu7Ldto8nmDVaKIZhfD?p=catalogue here's the complete code

Comment: `$('.jumbotron').css('background-image', 'url("'+imgHead[0]+''")');` - string concatenation is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem as I said in the comments is the string concatenation in assigning the background-image value.

```js
var imgHead = [
  '//placehold.it/64X64/ff0000',
  '//placehold.it/64X64/00ff00',
  '//placehold.it/64X64/0000ff'
];
var i = 0;

function Jumbotron() {
  if (i >= imgHead.length) {
    i = 0;
  }
  $('.jumbotron').animate({
    'opacity': '0'
  }, 200, function() {
    $(this).css('background-image', 'url("' + imgHead[i++] + '")').animate({
      'opacity': '1'
    }, 200);
  });

};
var intervalJumbotron = setInterval(Jumbotron, 3000);

Jumbotron();
```

```css
.jumbotron {
  height: 64px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="jumbotron"></div>
```

Comment: found a mistake in my code, now it works!! thanks a lot!